# How can I work with nested collection in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have collections inside collection which look like this:

```
=> [
 [
"id" => 3,
   "parent_id" => 2,
    "depth" => 1,
   "children" => [
     [
       "id" => 4,
       "parent_id" => 3,
       "depth" => 2,
       "children" => [
         [
           "id" => 5,
           "parent_id" => 4,
           "depth" => 3,
           "children" => [
             [
  [...]
```

How can I work on that?

```
 $result->count();
```

this return `1`

It behave like there is only 1 collection so I can't even use map or each to filter it. I need to filter with a max depth of 4.

I tried `reject()` but it's not working neither.

I could transform it to array but I want to use the nice collection methods...

Answer (score 2):

you need to iterate through your collection items

```
$result->children->map(function ($item) {
    // do some stuff with $item or you can no map through its children
    $item->children->map(function ($nestedItem) {
        // do some stuff with $nestedItem etc//
    });
});
```

an alternative would be to use `foreach` statement though

Comment: This return me : Null

Comment: post your code here, not just the dump of the variable

Comment: I'm using this https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable on my User model.
To get this dump i just do : 

    $result = $user->getDescendantsTree();

I can't post all the class of closure table here but the result is a nested collection.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the collection to Array and then use

```
 count($result, COUNT_RECURSIVE)
```